# Hook para log de queries e instrução Redirect

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

Estou usando hook para log de queries. No entanto quando uso redirect em vez de `load->view`, o array `db->queries` fica vazio. Preciso continuar usando a instrução redirect. Alguem pode me ajudar?

Estou usando [este modelo](https://bitbucket.org/jigarjain/codeigniter-log-all-db-queries-in-log-file/src/94841d0c2901981219c846a1c76bec9064b656a1/application/?at=master):

```
$hook['post_controller'] = array(     // 'post_controller' indicated execution of hooks after controller is finished
    'class' => 'Db_log',             // Name of Class
    'function' => 'logQueries',     // Name of function to be executed in from Class
    'filename' => 'db_log.php',    // Name of the Hook file
    'filepath' => 'hooks'         // Name of folder where Hook file is stored
);
class Db_log {

var $CI;

function __construct() {
    $this->CI = & get_instance(); // Create instance of CI
}
function logQueries() {

    $filepath = APPPATH . 'logs/QueryLog-' . date('Y-m-d') . '.php'; // Filepath. File is created in logs folder with name QueryLog
    $handle = fopen($filepath, "a+"); // Open the file

    $times = $this->CI->db->query_times; // We get the array of execution time of each query that got executed by our application(controller)

    foreach ($this->CI->db->queries as $key => $query) { // Loop over all the queries  that are stored in db->queries array
        $sql = $query . " \n Tempo de execução:" . $times[$key]; // Write it along with the execution time
        fwrite($handle, $sql . "\n\n");
    } 
    fclose($handle); // Close the file
}
```

A controller, em vez de usar um `$this->view("unimed")`
estou usando `redirect(base_url().'unimed');`

O que percebi é que ao usar o Redirect, ele perde (Ou reinicia) toda a controller.. e daí os valores da array `$this->db->queries` fica vazio
Preciso continuar usando o redirect pelo seguinte motivo:
ao usar um `load->view()` a url continua sendo a ultima que foi passada. E com o redirect a url vem limpa 
ex.: com

```
load->view("unimed")
```

após salvar um registro

a url vem: localhost/lucro/gestor/unimed/gravar/?id=&par=

ex.: com

```
redirect(base_url().'unimed')
```

após salvar  um registro a url vem localhost/lucro/gestor/unimed

Comment: Precisa dar mais detalhes. Quando esse hook é  excutado? poderia colocar o código dele? e da função onde está o `redirect()` ?

Comment: Estou usando este modelo.

Answer (score 1):

[RESOLVIDO]
Fiz da seguinte forma:
Criei no config.php um novo item:

$config['gera_arquivo_log'] = TRUE e 
Alterei o DB_driver incluindo a seguinte instrução:

```
    $ci = get_instance();
    if($ci->config->item('gera_arquivo_log')===TRUE and $this->save_queries === TRUE):
        Check::gravaFileLog($sql, $time_end - $time_start);
    endif;
```

Criei um método estático na minha classe Check :

```
public static function gravaFileLog($query, $time) {
    $filepath = APPPATH . 'logs/QueryLog-' . date('Y-m-d') . '.php'; // Filepath. File is created in logs folder with name QueryLog
    $handle = fopen($filepath, "a+"); // Open the file

    $sql = $query . " \n Tempo de execução:" . $time; // Write it along with the execution time
    fwrite($handle, $sql . "\n\n");
    fclose($handle); // Close the file
}
```

Se alguém tiver uma solução mais apropriada eu agradeço.